# getPostviewImageSize and setPostviewImageSize are "Not Available Now"

Tags: c#, api, camera, sony

By using the Sony Remote API I have to download the original image size by JSON from a Sony Alpha 7R to the connected computer (Windows 10, using C#).

The API docs says, the Postview Image Size is available for this camera. Calling the getPostviewImageSize I just receive a "Not Available Now".

Is there a different way to download the original images from the camera?

Looking forward to any hints,
Yvo

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to check here:

Check that your camera has the latest firmware. http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=ILCE7M2&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=download#/downloadTab

Check that you have the latest Smart Remote Control app installed on your camera - https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=is9104-npia09014_00-f00002

Comment: Hi Marlin, Thank you very much for the hint. With the suggested update I am able to get images in original (24M) resolution through the API. I have to check to other possibilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a question about the PlayMemories download:
We have to install the app on a fleet of Sony cameras and it has to be a stable setup (Firmware + PlayMemories) for a certain time.

Is there a way to download a specific installer version (e.g. 4.31 as currently version) of PlayMemories to guarantee a common setup for the fleet?

Looking forward to any hints.

Best regards,
Yvo

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is right (mldeveloper).
I just could not add comment so posting here my experience:

I only needed to update remote control application on camera.

Just navigate to playmemories on camera -> Select all apps -> then Update Remote Control. (You will need to sign in to sony site)